# programatically update value on control that implements ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, controls

I have a form with a button "fill form" that sets its model properties.
Model binding seems to be working fine but when I click the button, the controls implementing ControlValueAccessor do not get their values until I focus and blur them.

If the control is a plain html input, the model changes are visible right away.
If I set one of my custom controls, those wont reflect their changes until I click on them...

any clues?

I use angular 2 final.

this code DOES show the values, that is right after the form creating
    ngOnInit() {

```
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        myfield: ['', ]
    })

    this.myfield= this.form.controls['myfield'];

    ...

    this.obs.push(this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (params['myparam']) {
            this.model.myfield= params['tper_Codigo'];
            this.dataservice.get("miEntity", this.model).subscribe(somedata => {
                this.model = somedata;                   
            });
        }
    }));
```

this code does not

```
someClick() {
    //trying all sort of methods
    this.model = { myfield : 'aaaa'};
    this.form.patchValue({ myfield : 'bbbbb' });
    (<FormControl>this.form.controls['myfield']).updateValueAndValidity();
    (<FormControl>this.form.controls['myfield']).patchValue('cccc');

}
```

as i said before... if I click and blur the element, all the above methods DO reflect the value, so the value is setted, just not shown until blur

Comment: Do you have some code you can share?

Comment: ok, finally I decided to take a DEEP dive into angular2/material on github. I ended up refactoring tmy custom control's implementation in a very "ehem" simmilar way to theirs... now it works. I guess I will never know what part of mines wasnt working

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rewriting my control value accessor much more like the one in angular2/material, from angular team. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/input/input.ts

I STRONGLY recommend using these components as the ultimate reference in control building (I say control to differentiate gtom "view" of "component" and refer to monolithic ui base control). Any other examples fall short. I also recommend looking at some other projects who also did take these controls as a "inspiration", such as http://code.promactinfo.com/md2/

Very helpful and stuff that just works

thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

you can use setValue() function to update the control value. You can check the [api doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html)

Comment: I did it this way and also tryed many others. The intresting part is that it works right after the form's initialization. After that, changind the model and/or setting patch value has no effect. I also tryed manually triggering the digest cycle, refreshing the zone, etc etc. The only way to see the change in the control that implements controlvalueaccessor is to manually focussing it and the blurring... odd!

Comment: how do you bind your data in template?

Comment: Hi Mavlam, as I sad in a comment before, I ended up re-writing my component taking most of the CVA from angular2/material sources. My code was pretty simmilar to begin with, but for some reason, mild changes  ended up making it work as it was supposed. I would like to go back to this issue and figure out why it happened but i am on a tight schedule and I'm in a solve now ask later mode